# RoutedCommand with parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, routed-commands

I'm playing around with *RoutedCommand*, and I'm having an issue with finding how can I pass a parameter so that my *Executed* method will have it in e.Parameter ?

My RoutedCommand:

```
public static readonly RoutedCommand Foo = new RoutedCommand();
```

Usage:

```
menuItem.Command = Commands.Foo;
```

Executed:

```
private void Foo_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            object parameter = e.Parameter; // this is always null
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're parameter is always `null` because you never set it anywhere

You can set it using the `CommandParameter` property

```
menuItem.Command = Commands.Foo;
menuItem.CommandParameter = "Bar";
```

Comment: doh! Overlooked this one... anyway thank you for a fast answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should use  [MenuItem.CommandParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.commandparameter.aspx).

For example, you could set binding to some property, from which parameter is delivered.